# Present a View before Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an app that will use a tab bar controller. But before this tab bar controller appear I need to authenticate the user. So I'm trying to load a View before the Tab bar controller appear.
Here is what I did so far:
I'm using a Tabbed Application, and in the storyboard is the tab bar controller.
I created a View Controller called LoginViewController, which contains it's own xib.

So in the **AppDelegate** didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method I did this:

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:NULL];
self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
[self.window addSubview:loginViewController.view];
```

Then, in the **LoginViewController** implementation I created a method that will be called when the login is successful. Here is how it looks like:

```
- (void)removeLoginView
{
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate removeLoginView];
}
```

Now I don't know how I should implement this method in the AppDelegate.
How could I remove the loginViewController and set the TabBar controller from the storyboard to be shown? Or any other suggestions on how to do something like this.

Note: I saw some suggestions about using presentModalViewController, but it has been deprecated.

Comment: I suggest you to choose any different way if you have two types of user in you application i.e.administrator or user,sender or receiver.Because if then may be you need to show different view for both types of user at that time after login you have to check that which type of user logged in and based on that you have to load that viewcontroller in your tabbar.That means before login you have already loaded tab bar.so you to have relaod tabbar with respective viewcontroller after login or you have to check which user is logged in and based on that you have to show view in same viewcontroller.

Comment: otherwise someone has given answer...first load tabbar with viewcontrollers and then set it as rootviewcontroller and then present loginviewcontroller on it. I have done same thing in my app...and now facing some issues that i have mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I don't pretend to have any different types of users (all with facebook).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `tab bar controller` as `window.rootViewController` and at the end of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method just use the `presentViewController:animated:completion` method (which replace the deprecated `presentModalViewController` method):

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:NULL];
self.window.rootViewController = tabarViewController;
[tabarViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil]
```

Comment: In a storyboard, how to get tabarViewController? tabarViewController is set to be a root window in the storyboard.